# Apache Commons Math Combinations Class: Ordered List instead of the default random list

Tags: java, math, combinations

The below given code

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.util.Combinations;
import java.util.*;
public class CExample
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Combinations c = new Combinations(5,3);
       List<int[]> al = new ArrayList<int[]>();
       for(int[] iterate : c){
            al.add(iterate);
       }
       Collections.sort(al,Comparator.comparing((int[] arr)->arr[0]));
    }
 }
```

sorts the combinations by the first element of the array arr only as shown below:

> 0 1 2
>   0 1 3
>   0 2 3
>   0 1 4
>   0 2 4
>   0 3 4
>   1 2 3
>   1 2 4
>   1 3 4
>   2 3 4

How can I sort it by second element (and possibly third, forth and so on) as well.

Comment: Store those values in a list and sort the list?

Comment: @MikePierce the code is working when r=2 only. How to sort it for r greater than 2?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys! I got my solution. Thanks to the post from @gdejohn. The solution is given here.

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.util.Combinations;
import java.util.*;
import static java.util.Comparator.comparing;

public class CExample2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Combinations c = new Combinations(10,3);
         List<int[]> al = new ArrayList<int[]>();
         for(int[] iterate : c){
             al.add(iterate);
         }
         int in[]={1}; //in is {1,2} when r=4 and is {1,2,3} when r is 5 and so on
         sortA(al,0,in);
     }
     public static void sortA(List<int[]> al, int first, int... rest){
         Comparator<int[]> comparator = comparing(array -> array[first]);
         for (int index : rest) {
             comparator = comparator.thenComparing(array -> array[index]);
         }
         al.sort(comparator);
         for(int[] iterate : al){
             for(int i=0;i<iterate.length; i++){
                 System.out.print(iterate[i] +" ");    
             }
             System.out.println();
          }
     }
}
```

Any comment on the efficiency will be highly appreciated as in cases when n is up to 100 and r is up to 20 let suppose.